# What does 'if((mask | u)==u)' mean?

Tags: c++, if-statement, bitwise-operators

This is the recurrence relation of `maximum` `sum` subset problem.

The complete code is:

```
if ((mask | u) == u)
    dp[u] = max(max(0, dp[u ^ mask] + array[I], dp[u]);
```

What does exactly mean the following if-statement?

```
if((mask | u) == u)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is the complete code?

Comment: Also could you please share the values of mask and u, this will help us to write a better answer/explanation

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem. Please explain more what it is about.

Comment: it depends on the types of `mask` and `u`. Unless you tell us what it is, the code could mean anything. Please include a [mre]

Comment: To second @idclev463035818: operators may be overloaded in C++ with a complete different meaning. (Think of the stream operators (ab-)using the bit-shift operators.) I assume `mask` and `u` are some kind of unsigned integrals but you should [edit] your question and tell this explicitly.

Comment: I gave your `if((mask | u) == u)` a different meaning than that described in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949446/7478597) (which I consider probably as correct): [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e08b73d154cd348) :-)

Comment: I suggest you to learn about [bitwise-operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) and [bitwise-algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-algorithms/). They'll help you to understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary `OR` for **binary** values `A`, `B` evaluates as `(1)` if **either** `A = 1` **or** `B = 1`. These bitwise operations extend to *strings* of binary digits. In `C/C++`, that's most commonly expressed as `integral types`.

```
OR    | A = 0 | A = 1 |
-----------------------
B = 0 | (0)   | (1)   |
-----------------------
B = 1 | (1)   | (1)   |
-----------------------
```

(forgive the ASCII art - more concise illustrations and links are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_%7C))

---

`mask = {m(n - 1), m(n - 2), .., m(1), m(0)}` : `(n)` binary digits (bits) `m(i)`

`u = {u(n - 1), u(n - 2), .., u(1), u(0)}` : `(n)` binary digits (bits) `u(i)`

---

Let's consider **`(m(i) | u(i)) == u(i)`** for: **`i = {0, .., n - 1}`** ; should *any* of these bit-wise comparisons be **false**, then the expression **`((mask | u) == u)`** evaluates as **false**.

From the `OR` table we can conclude that the expression is false **if and only if** `m(i) = 1` and `u(i) = 0`. That is: **`m(i) | u(i) == (1) OR (0) == (1)`** which **does not** equal **`u(i) == 0`**

---

A more concise way of expressing the issue is that if `mask` has a bit at a position `(i)` **set** to `(1)`, and `u` has a bit at the *same* position **cleared** to `(0)`, then `(mask | u)` **cannot** equal `u`.

Answer (score 6):

It means: “Are all bits of `mask` in `u`”.
So if there is a bit in `mask` not in `u` this test returns false.

For instance with `mask=0b001` and `u=0b011` it returns `true`. But with `mask=0b101` and `u=0b011` it returns `false` because the third bit of `mask` is not set in `u`.